# Longest Palindromic Substring in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, time-complexity

I'm trying to solve the Longest Palindromic Substring problem in O(N^2) time complexity.

Problem:
Given a string s, find the longest palindromic substring in s. You may assume that the maximum length of s is 1000.

Example 1:

```
Input: "babad"
Output: "bab"
Note: "aba" is also a valid answer.
```

Example 2:

```
Input: "cbbd"
Output: "bb"
```

My solution:

```
var longestPalindrome = function(s) {
    if(!s || s.length === 0)    return "";
    
    let start = 0;
    let end = 0;
    
    for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        let len1 = expand(s, i, i);
        let len2 = expand(s, i, i+1);
        let size = Math.max(len1, len2);
        if(size > end-start) {
            start = Math.floor(i - ((size-1) / 2));
            end = Math.floor(i + (size/2));
        }
    }
    
    return s.substring(start, end+1);
};

const expand = (str, left, right) => {
    let l = left;
    let r = right;
    while(l >= 0 && r < str.length && str[l] === str[r]) {
        l--;
        r++;
    }
    
    return r-l-1;
}
```

My solution works for the example 1, but it fails for the example 2. It returns "cbb" instead of "bb". Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough, replace

```
start = Math.floor(i - ((size-1) / 2));
```

with

```
start = i - Math.floor((size-1) / 2);
```

Your complexity will be, as you outlined earlier, `O(n^2)`. If you care, it's possible to get `O(n log(n))`, but this technique is considerably more difficult. It involves hashing the corpus(input string) in such a way that you can get substring hashes in `O(1)` with `O(n)` precomp, then for each start character (or pair of adjacent similar characters) binary search your way to the LPS at that index (so you'll need reverse hashes as well). I'm sure you can find a better explanation somewhere out there on the internet. GL!

Answer (score -1):

For illustration only:
the following will work but, obviously, **it is not O(n^2)**!

```js
["babad","dessert","the fastest racecar was his","A reviver.","boring"].forEach(s=>
  console.log(s+': '+longpal(s)));
  
function longpal(s){
  let r=s.split('').reverse().join(''); // reverse string
  let p,l,m=[0,0]; // [pos,len] of best match
  for(p=0;p<s.length;p++){   
   for(l=s.length-p; l>m[1];l--)
    // remember p and l only if it is a longer match 
    if (r.indexOf(s.substr(p,l))>-1) m=[p,l];
  } 
  return s.substr(...m)
}
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I'm looking for a O(n^2) solution. Your solution has a indexOf inside a nested for loop, it is not O(n^2)

Comment: Yes, that is true. I will have a look at your approach again but somehow I doubt that an O(n^2) solution is possible.

Comment: My idea is to start from the middle and expand to the left and right if they have the same character because it is a palindrome for same character

Comment: O(n log(n)) is possible, cars10m